# Lenovo Y560 won't boot unless it's on AC power

Tags: 11.04, battery

I have a Lenovo Y560 and have installed Ubuntu 11.04 (64 bit) via Wubi. When I start the notebook on battery, Ubuntu hangs before the login screen. Any workarounds?

Comment: I'm using a lenovo y560d. And since upgrading from ubuntu 10.10 to 11.04, 2 days back, i'm facing the same issue. I think there is some problem with the kernel 2.6.38 Was able to start my laptop only after plugging it in. This is a critical issue, I won't be able to start my laptop while on move. :(

Answer (score 2):

I have the Y560 as well and am experiencing the same problem.  I tried downgrading to older kernels but still have the same issue.  I did find this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/775950 and verified that I have the same kernel panic and message happening. There is also someone with a Y460 with the same problem here [Lenovo Y460 won't boot most of the time unless plugged in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35112/lenovo-y460-wont-boot-most-of-the-time-unless-plugged-in)

Update 2011-07-16: It appears that the latest kernel update (2.6.38-10-generic) has fixed the issue on the Y560.

Comment: It appears that the latest kernel update (2.6.38-10-generic) has fixed the issue on the Y560.

Comment: Please add the comment to the answer.