# Lenovo Y460 Shutdown/Reboot/Logoff doesn't work

Tags: ati, shutdown, lenovo

This is a part of the massive dump of problems I'm encountering with my Lenovo Y460 and Ubuntu.

Problem: Cannot shutdown/reboot/logoff.

- Logoff issue: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1791439
- Shutdown and Reboot often freezes without doing anything. Currently can only use hard reset.
- Maybe related to the tricks I did to work around the ATI/Intel issue. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/51176/lenovo-y460-ati-powerxpress-issue

I'm not sure where I can find the shutdown/reboot logs. If you tell me I'll be happy to provide them.

Not sure what to do as of right now other than never shutdown/reboot or logoff

Comment: most likely due to your graphics issues - have a look at my previous reply on the 2.6.39 kernel and catalyst 11.6.  You could also try the edgers ppa to see if the latest graphics stack improves matters.

Comment: Can you explain/link this Edger PPA? Also I'll try to get the latest kernel (clonezilla first, of course.)

Comment: This is the latest drivers from the ubuntu graphics team - they can be very unstable, but since you are have lots of graphics issues, you may have better luck than you currently are having.  Remember - clonezilla first before adding this ppa.  https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa

Comment: Yeah that's fine, i don't have important files. I also have Windows on another HDD, so I'll be fine if anything goes wrong.

Comment: Worked. Just 1 major issue left now. If you answer I would accept your solution as it is your solution that helped me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Overview:**

The concept of switchable Graphics support in Linux - whether ATI & Intel, or NVIDIA & Intel - is currently in development.

Various workarounds are available, but I suspect strongly, these issues will be eventually resolved, but you may have to wait some time for stable solutions.

In the interim, may I suggest you look at the latest graphics drivers and an updated Kernel.

In my experience, if the boot/shutdown issues are not Power Management related, then they are most often Graphics related.

Remember - use a good imaging tool such as Clonezilla so that you can easily rollback if stuff goes wrong.

**Updating your intel drivers & mesa stack:**

The latest "bleeding edge" intel drivers can be found by adding the Edgers PPA.  These work best with the 2.6.39 kernel.

These drivers can be very unstable - but given your current graphics issues, it is worth a try.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

this should update your graphics including your intel driver.  If it doesnt then

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

Assuming this works - my recommendation would then to be to disable the xorg-edgers ppa from your software sources.  Updates to this PPA are frequent - and there could be a strong possibility that one or more updates could break your system.

Before you upgrade from the PPA again - take a quick image backup just incase the revised updates breaks your system.

By fortunate coincidence, the latest ATI Catalyst driver (11.6) can also work with the same 2.6.39 kernel - see the [AU question and answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50687/fglrx-catalyst-11-6-is-it-compatible-with-kernel-2-6-39/50688#50688).

If you couple both the intel and ATI updates with the vgaswitcharoo trick - together with the latest Kernel, hopefully this should resolve both the boot & shutdown issues as well as most of your graphics issues.

**Before upgrading to 11.10**

Before you upgrade to 11.10 when it is finished in October this year, you should "ppa_purge" the xorg-edgers PPA as well as remove the ATI Catalyst driver.

This should allow you to upgrade successfully.

Comment: Yes, I would definitely disable xorg-edgers, as when I installed those updates it broke the ATI catalyst driver and required ppa_purge to fix.